Multiplicative linear functional on noncommutative unital Banach algebra is bounded and norm-decreasing
It is a standard theorem that, for an abelian unital Banach algebra, every nonzero multiplicative linear functional is bounded and has norm at most $1$. I don't see why the proof can't work word-by-word for noncommutative unital Banach algebras. But, strangely, all the textbooks (Conway/Folland/Murphy) I can see state this theorem with the requirement of the algebra being abelian. Is there a special reason for this requirement? Is it because there are counterexamples for noncommutative algebras, or is the validity for noncommutative algebras too obvious? Thanks in advance.

Note that multiplicative + linear implies that it vanishes on commutators $xy-yx$. So, the theorem on Abelian Banach algebras is the interesting theorem.

As ameg says in the comments, the theorem is uninteresting in the noncommutative case, and reduces immediately to the commutative case, because every such functional factors through the abelianization (the quotient by the closure of the ideal generated by commutators). The abelianization is even frequently zero, e.g. already for $M_n(\mathbb{C}), n \ge 2$.
